# Specific design issue when dealing with subcomponents in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Let's say I have 2 components, `cmp1` and `cmp2`. 
`cmp1` will loop through a list and create `cmp2`'s for every item. In `cmp2`, I want to display the person data.

```dart
//component 1
@Component(selector: 'cmp1', 
           templateUrl: 'cmp1.html', 
           publishAs: 'cmp')    
class cmp1 {
  List myList;

  cmp1(){
    this.myList = [{'name':'foo','age':20},{'name':'bar','age':30}];
  }
}
```

---

In `cmp1.html`

```dart
<cmp2 ng-repeat='person in cmp.myList'></cmp2>
```

---

```dart
//component 2
@Component(selector: 'cmp2', 
           templateUrl: 'cmp2.html', 
           publishAs: 'cmp')    
class cmp2 {}
```

---

In `cmp2.html`

```dart
<span>name: *display person name*</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it this way you need a `@NgAttr('person') Map person;` in `cmp2`.

// cmp1.html

```dart
<cmp2 person="{{person}}" ng-repeat="person in cmp.myList"></cmp2>
```

// cmp2.html

```dart
<span>name: {{cmp2.person['name']}}</span>
```

#### not tested

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work if I put in string values. 

However in my actual case im looping over model instances. When I try to call the username getter of the current model instance in my cmp2 template it says : 

Class 'String' has no instance getter 'username'.
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'username'
Receiver: "Instance of 'BetModel'"
Arguments: []

Comment: I haven't worked with Angular.dart for a while. Maybe it works better if you use `@NgTwoWay` instead of `@NgAttr`.

Comment: Yes, NgAttr only works with Strings, use `@NgOneWay` or `@NgTwoWay` to bind to object instances.